# Numpy: Randomly replace N values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy array `array` of a given shape `array.shape`. How can I randomly replace `N` values from this array by values from given distribution (e.g. from normal distribution)?

Something like `noisy = array + np.random.normal(0, 1, array.shape)`, but only for `N` values.

Comment: The obvious way is to pick N random indices to replace with `numpy.random.choice` and `replace=False`, but `replace=False` has a truly awful implementation they're stuck with for backward compatibility.

Comment: @user2357112 is it work than `random.sample`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: On one hand, `random.sample` doesn't try to shuffle an array of all possible indices just to draw N of them; on the other hand, it's written in Python, which hurts its constant factor. Depending on how lazy I'm feeling and how much it matters, I might actually write code to switch between `random.sample` and `numpy.random.choice` depending on the proportion of items to select.